# Powershell - Extract Non-UTF-8 Characters from multiple files and Re-write the new files and create a new file with the bad Characters (ebcdic?)

Tags: regex, powershell, utf-8

I have a small script that I can use to find and replace characters or strings in a file.  It works and I can use it to replace the non UTF-8 characters.

What I need to do is run the script once and replace all the invalid data in one shot AND create another file that has the File name and bad characters.
Right now I have to run the script over and over with however many invalid characters I can ID by eyeball.  Then I edit my tracking file with the contents of the script I ran and the File I ran it against.
Not efficient at all.  Just to be clear, I have almost no clue how to code the second part of keeping track of what is corrected.
Can anyone offer a better way of doing this?

Thank you,
-Ron

```
$old = 'BAD DATA'
$new = ' '

$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.* -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "$old", "$new" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Here is a sample of my DATA...

"PARTHENIA STREET °212   "," ","                              "," ","CAUGA PARK           "

The data ' °' in HEX is c2 and b0.  The original file before FTP is a single byte HEX 09.  Not only did it convert wrong it added a btye to the file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `non UTF-8` characters and why are they _bad_? Isn't this just a case of trying to repair something that was written by some other script without using the UTF-8 BOM ? I would rather fix that than fixing the config files afterwards..

Comment: Ah - Good Question.  The files are coming from a Mainframe that is in EBCDIC.  They were created via DB2 unload.  it is not known how the invalid characters became present in the database but when the file is FTP'ed (RAW) the invalid data is messing up the system that is intended to ingest the data.

Comment: I think you mean ascii, not utf-8.  Did you download the file in ftp ascii mode, not binary mode?  Ascii mode might not translate the text correctly.

Comment: 0x09 is TAB character. I can not understand how 0x09 became 0xc2b0. You need to understand when and why it changes, and why it becomes 2 characters.

Comment: ebcdic is not ascii or utf8.  You may have to translate it if your ftp client can't:  https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/17/working-with-non-native-powershell-encoding-ebcdic/

Comment: Hi All,
Great questions and observations.  Yes, we have translation issues/FTP issues.  It is unknown at this time how the characters are being generated and when the sFTP is initiated, the extra characters that are generated IS of great concern.  That area is out of my control.  I have the files and I now have to deal with them.
Is there a way to capture the data I need to change AND change the data in a single script?

-Ron

Comment: Is it ftp or sftp?

Comment: All Data transfers are sFTP, So yes I have only a single option sFTP (RAW same as 
 BINARY)

Comment: 0xC2 0xB0 *is* UTF-8, namely the degree character [U+00B0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b0/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example translating ebcidic to ascii based on [ASCII-to-EBCDIC or EBCDIC-to-ASCII](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aab31e26-0edd-422c-92e4-158068221e32/asciitoebcdic-or-ebcdictoascii?forum=csharpgeneral) and [Working with non-native PowerShell encoding (EBCDIC)](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/17/working-with-non-native-powershell-encoding-ebcdic/), but the ebcidic file is completely unrecognizable.  It doesn't have a BOM.
The file was downloaded with sftp, but it sounds like it was already corrupted.

```
"hi`tthere","how`tare" | set-content file.txt  # tab 0x09 in the middle 

# From ASCII to EBCDIC
$asciibytes = get-content file.txt -Encoding byte 
$rawstring = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($asciibytes)
$ebcdicbytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('ebcdic-cp-us').getbytes($rawstring)
$ebcdicbytes | set-content ebcidic.txt -Encoding Byte

# From EBCDIC to ASCII
$ebcidicbytes = get-content ebcidic.txt -Encoding byte 
$rawstring = [System.Text.Encoding]::getencoding('ebcdic-cp-us').GetString($ebcidicbytes)
$asciibytes = [system.text.encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($rawstring)
$asciibytes | set-content ascii.txt -Encoding Byte
```

Here's a script called nonascii.ps1 that strips non-ascii characters (not between space and tilde in the ascii table, and also tab) and writes to the same filename.

```
(get-content $args[0]) -replace '[^ -~\t]' | set-content $args[0]
```

Note that powershell 5.1's get-content can't recognize utf8 no bom files without the '-encoding utf8' parameter.

```
get-content file -encoding utf8
```

Also note that powershell 6.2 and above can use any encoding known by .net, although tab completion doesn't reflect this:

```
"hi`tthere" | set-content ebcidic.txt -encoding ebcdic-cp-us
get-content ebcidic.txt -encoding ebcdic-cp-us
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the code snippet.  Translating the Data is not the task I was assigned.  I need to remove the bad data and document the action.  I could really use a bit of direction in how to accomplish this.
Thanks,
-Ron

Comment: Thank you! Now I just have to figure out the record keeping part of the script.  But I will say, that was pretty cool to do all that in a single line!

-Ron